# Reset battery history after unplugging charger?

Tags: settings, battery, charging

As far as I can tell, the stats on the Battery page of Settings records the time from when the battery is booted up onwards. What I'd rather want it to do, is to reset that counter whenever I disconnect the charger so that I can monitor more accurately how long a full charge lasts.

[image: Settings > Battery]

I am aware that there are 3rd party apps like Battery Monitor widget for these things but I'd really want to use the pre-built in options that came with Android.

Comment: Why not just use third party apps? They are easy enough to install. Otherwise the most you can do is to estimate graphically by looking at the rate of descent of the graph. Battery remaining time is impossible to estimate accurately, and measuring battery life time only makes sense when you collected data over multiple charges. Any simple measurements you collect yourself is most likely going to be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes with Android is the dialer. Try to "call" `*#*#4636#*#*`. On most devices, this gives you the choice between "since boot", "since last unplugged", and more. Admittedly, the graphics is not that nice as with your screenshot :)

[image: Test menu] [image: Battery history]

Comment: Erm, I can't see the Battery History option. :o https://www.dropbox.com/s/zktglwmhr6l89nd/Screenshot_2012-07-24-16-26-52.png

Comment: I too cant see "Battery History" option in my rooted LG Optimus One (P500), running stock ROM 2.3.3 as well.

Comment: Oh. So your phone (or rather the used ROM) is one of the few that dropped that point (or was it dropped somewhere in Gingerbread? I just notice it's gone on my phones as well (CM7), and it has been there before with stock Froyo) -- sorry for that (btw, you didn't state your device name and Android version used -- maybe that proves helpful in this case, so you might want to add it to your original question).

Comment: I just did some research: That option has indeed been removed with gingerbread (read [here](http://www.cri.ch/sven/doku.php/blog/fixed-spareparts-for-gingerbread) and [here](http://www.techofweb.com/technology/battery-info-gingerbread.html))

Comment: Ahh I didn't think it was necessary, anyway this is an ST17i running on pure Ice Cream Sandwich

Comment: Your question tells otherwise -- as you seem to miss exactly that. Moreover, stats on wake locks are gone as well because of that, and they were quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted and also if you flashed a clock work mod, then you can clear battery status by

**1.Reboot into Recovery**-->
**2.Advanced**-->
**3.Clear Battery Status**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [setOnBatteryLocked method](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/os/BatteryStatsImpl.java) from Android:

```
        // We will reset our status if we are unplugging after the
        // battery was last full, or the level is at 100, or
        // we have gone through a significant charge (from a very low
        // level to a now very high level).
        if (oldStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL
                || level >= 90
                || (mDischargeCurrentLevel < 20 && level >= 80)) {
            doWrite = true;
            resetAllStatsLocked();
            mDischargeStartLevel = level;
```